# why keypress event does not dispatch

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day.
I want to simulate 'tab' key pressing from my function. I want to allow input only between some range, and after, return cursor to the other range. And if user input more then positions in the range the cursor should be moved to the next range automatically. 
I searched some examples, ideas. And found very similar examples in the different sources. Tried... and it doesn't work in my case.

[*] -  means the input range

Please, can anyone help me?

My code:

```js
var starts = [22, 47];
var ends = [24, 50];
var tabIndex = 1;
var inputIndex = 0;
var textarea = $("#inputText");

function setSelectionRange(input, start, end) {
  if (input.setSelectionRange) {
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(start, end);
  } else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', end);
    range.moveStart('character', start);
    range.select();
  }
}

function setCaretToPos(input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  textarea.keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $('form').submit();
      e.preventDefault();
    } else if (e.keyCode == 9) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (tabIndex >= starts.length) {
        tabIndex = 0;
      }
      setCaretToPos(document.getElementById("inputText"), starts[tabIndex]);
      tabIndex++;
    }
  });
});

textarea.on("input", function() {
  var pos = $(this).val().slice(0, this.selectionStart).length;
  if (inputIndex <= starts.length) {
    var before = textarea.val().slice(0, starts[inputIndex]);

    if (this.selectionStart > starts[inputIndex] && this.selectionStart <= ends[inputIndex]) {
      $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, this.selectionStart) + $(this).val().slice(this.selectionStart + 1));
      setCaretToPos(this, pos);
    }
    var after = textarea.val().slice(ends[inputIndex]);
    if ($(this).val().indexOf(before) !== 0) {
      $(this).val(before + $(this).val().slice(before.length, ends[inputIndex]) + after);
    } else if (this.selectionStart >= ends[inputIndex]) {
      $(this).val(before + $(this).val().slice(before.length, ends[inputIndex]) + after);
      inputIndex++;
      var e = $.Event("keypress", {
        keyCode: 9
      });
      e.keyCode = 9;
      $("textarea").trigger(e);
    }
  } else {
    inputIndex = 0;
  }

});

setCaretToPos(document.getElementById("inputText"), starts[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="/myAction" method="post" modelAttribute="displayVal">
    <p><textarea id="inputText" name="inputText" rows="25" cols="25" style="overflow: auto" required>some long text. Input **. Text again. Input 2: ***.</textarea></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I saw examples [here](http://jsfiddle.net/taj8H/35/)

[and here](http://jsfiddle.net/DxER9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the

```
var textarea = $("#inputText");
```

statement inside the

```
$(document).ready...
```

event, because when this code is executed, the DOM has not been render in html.
See below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#inputText").keypress(function(e) {
```

Comment: thanks. I've run my code in snipped and was surprised: worked, but didn't on my page - thank you!